# Determination of $f(x)$

Tags: continuity

A continuous function $f$ satisfies $f(x+f(x))=f(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. prove that $f(x)$ is constant.

$f(f(0))=f(0)$. I am unable to proceed further.

Comment: $f(x)=0$, i think.

Comment: @kingtut how does it give the result if f(x) is polynomial

Comment: I agree with John

Comment: @JohnLou $f$ can be any constant function!

Comment: Are we to assume that $x+f(x)\in [0,1]$ $\forall x$?

Comment: @lulu No, we are not

Comment: @GHD Here's my issue with $f$ being any constant function. If that is the case, then $x+f(x)$ may not be in the domain of $f(x)$ when $x$ is and vice versa.

Comment: @GhD  Ok, then what does $f(x+f(x))$ mean?

Comment: @john lou domain of f(x) is R(all real)  it satisfies this functional equation when x is in[0,1]

Comment: @lulu It means value of $f$ on $x+f(x)$!!

Comment: @GhD   If $f$ is defined on all $\mathbb R$ but the functional equation only holds for $x\in [0,1]$ then $f$ does not need to be a constant.  Suppose $f(x)=1$ on $[-\infty,2]$ but $f(x)=3-x$ for $x>2$

Comment: @lulu This is not my question.

Comment: @GhD, ah true.  In any case, I see that your posted counterexample is effectively the same as mine.  I think the problem is meant to require that everything stays in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @SiddharthaRaja  As you can see, you need to clarify the domain of your function and the region in which the functional equation is to hold.  Look at the counterexamples you have been given.  To exclude those you need to clarify your conditions.

Comment: @lulu yes. or perhaps in $\mathbb R_+$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $f(x)=0$ when $x\in\mathbb R_+\cup\{0\}$ and put $f(x)=x$ when $x\in\mathbb R_-$. This is not constant and satisfy youR question.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: but if the functional equation does not hold outside of the given interval for $x$, then your comment does not apply...

Comment: @TheSimpliFire  The problem is very poorly worded.  The OP insists that the functional equation is only meant to hold for $x\in [0,1]$ and the function here does indeed satisfy the functional equation there.